# Terminal: Swift Build command does not work

Tags: swift, macos, terminal

When I am using Swift Package builder in the OSX terminal, it does now work.

```
swift build
```

I get:

> :0: error: no such file or directory: 'build'

REPL works and all the snapshots seem to be installed. Does anyone know the issue?

Comment: Package manager is not a part of every snapshot yet.  Download and install an older version that has swift-build in it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It helps. By Default command line tool will have nothing selected. Once you click a drop down will come and you can select the latest xCode. This will associate the XCode tool chain to the command line and you can use swift build, swift package init etc. You may not have to set the path also.
[image]

Comment: This also help if I got this error:
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/llbuild.framework/Versions/A/llbuild
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/swift-build
  Reason: image not found
fish: 'swift build' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to download the development snapshot, not the release one - https://swift.org/builds/development/xcode/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-08-a/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-08-a-osx.pkg

Answer (score 0):

`/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin` should be appended before `$PATH` in your `.bashrc`:

`PATH=/Applications/IBM/node/bin:/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to install latest Xcode and change the command line tools to point to latest XCode Version. It can be done by going to Xcode > preferences > Locations > Command line tools.
Change it to Xcode (version number).